# proliant dl360 G7 + debian squeeze

Tags: debian, hp, hp-proliant

has anyone installed debian squeeze on an HP proliant dl360 G7 ?

my concerns are about hardware raid, does it works?

on http://wiki.debian.org/HP/ProLiant i see that DL360 G6
is not working.

thank you

Answer (score 3):

The DL360 G6 and G7  use the same Smart Array P410 RAID controller, so I'd expect the same result.

You can certainly substitute an approved controller and disable the onboard Smart Array controller. I do this with DL380 G7 systems that I use for Solaris installations.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that HP only provides a driver for specific kernel versions, and [some people using CentOS have had problems trying to  upgrade their kernel](http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?24,135609,136061) because HP didn't release an updated driver at the same time.

Looking at HP's [DL360 G7 site](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareIndex.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodNameId=4091409&prodTypeId=15351&prodSeriesId=4091408&swLang=8&taskId=135&swEnvOID=4103) now, there's management and BIOS updates (but no drivers) for Debian 5 (lenny) and nothing at all for 6 (squeeze).  If you don't install a supported distribution (with a supported kernel) then I would suggest that the best thing to do would be to disable RAID in the P410 controller, and use Linux's software raid to create the array.

Answer (score 1):

All SmartArray controllers have driver also in stock kernel, so there is no problem with Debian. The driver is cciss and disks appear under /dev/cciss/.
I had issues on DL380 G7 with network card during installation. It uses bnx2 driver and needs firmware, which is not on netinst CD, so I had to put the firmware on virtual floppy.

Answer (score 0):

I've got severol DL360 G6 with Lenny and 1 with Squeeze with RAID Support.

But I used it with SAS disk and not SATA.

It perfectly works in that case but the hardware raid with SATA disk is not supported.
Regards

Pierre

Answer (score 0):

That issue is only for the very basic edition of the DL360 G6 that had the cheapo B110i controller, if you have a controller that starts with E or P (i.e E400i, P812 etc.) you'll be fine.